# C language: how to return string array from function

Tags: c

So i have this user input:

```
char usercommand[512];
fgets(usercommand, 512, stdin);
```

And i want to split this line by space and populate my `array`.
So i have this `array`:

```
char arguments[2];
```

And this `function`:

```
void parseuserinput(char *c, char *arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok(c, " ");
    while (pch)
    {
        arr[i] = pch;
        i++;
        pch = strtok(NULL, "");
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
parseuserinput(usercommand, arguments);
```

And my `array` is still empty although i can see that my `function` parseuserinput insert elements into my `array`.

Comment: 1) `char arguments[2];` is too small.  try `char arguments[200];`  2) `parseuserinput()` does not null character terminate `arr`.  3) "my array is still empty" --> post the code that shows that  4) Post input used.

Comment: 2 elements is enough for me

Comment: Did you mean `char *arguments[2];`?

Comment: I also try this

Comment: @DannyNitman 2 is only enough to store a character and a null character - a very short string.

Comment: @chux I think he is trying to store two pointers, for each part of the split string mentioned, so AntonH has it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes that does appears to be the reveled issue.  Yet given  `usercommand[512]` and `strtok(NULL, "")`,  `char *arguments[sizeof usercommand / 2];` may be prudent.

Comment: @chux nice point. Within the loop `strtok(NULL, "")` should be `strtok(NULL, " ")` with that added space in the delimiter spec. Yet, if the string has to be split in two parts, there is no need for a loop. If `strtok(c, " ");` returns `NULL`, there are not two parts, othrewise the two pointers are to the original string, and the return value from `strtok`.

Comment: @chux SO is flooded now by the questions asked by people too lazy to read the C book.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I agree with [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931201/c-language-how-to-return-string-array-from-function?noredirect=1#comment82831827_47931201)  yet SO policy is [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @chux it is overcorrectness  not the niceness. This kind of questions waste time of many people who read this. There is a difference between the question asked by the beginner who learns the language and does not understand something and this kind of questions. At least I see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing a pointer value in a variable of type `char`. Then you are pointing to parts of the string. A possible solution would be to use `char* arguments[2]` and then use `strdup()` to duplicate strings and store the address of the duplicated string in those `char *[]`.

```
void parseuserinput(char *c, char *arr[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok(c, " ");
    while (pch)
    {
        arr[i] = strdup(pch);
        ...
    }
}
```

Here, we have duplicated each of the tokenized `string` pointed by `pch` and stored it. Array of `char*` being decayed into a pointer to the first elements of the array enables us to make changes to it, which in turn lets us realize *returning value from the function*.

And how many positions of the `char*[]` have been filled. You are incrementing `i` and this `i` inturn denotes the number of elements of the `char*` array correctly filled. You can return it from the function to give an idea to the callee function regarding the number of elements correctly filled.

```
int parseuserinput(char *c, char *arr)
{
    ...
    return i;
}
```

`strdup` - check it's return value and free it when you are done working with it.